# How can I maximize an IE window created by VBA with SHDocVw.InternetExplorer command?

Tags: vba, excel, shdocvw

As the title says, I'm trying to maximize an internet explorer window that was created using the following command:

```
Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
```

Instead of:

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

---

Here's the full code:

```
Sub wpieautologin()
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Dim NOME_EMPRESA, CNPJ, CPF, COD_ACESSO As String
Dim Lookup_Range As Range

Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = False
ie.Navigate "http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/simplesnacional/controleacesso/autentica.aspx?id=6"

NOME_EMPRESA = Range("B8").Value
Set Lookup_Range = Range("B12:E500")

CNPJ = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(NOME_EMPRESA, Lookup_Range, 2, False)
CPF = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(NOME_EMPRESA, Lookup_Range, 3, False)
COD_ACESSO = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(NOME_EMPRESA, Lookup_Range, 4, False)

Do
Loop Until ie.readystate = 4
Call ie.Document.GetElementByID("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_txtCNPJ").SetAttribute("value", CNPJ)
Call ie.Document.GetElementByID("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_txtCPFResponsavel").SetAttribute("value", CPF)
Call ie.Document.GetElementByID("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_txtCodigoAcesso").SetAttribute("value", COD_ACESSO)
ie.Visible = True

>'What should I write here to maximize my IE Window? 
>'Already tried a few solutions, but they works only when the IE is created by the command 
>'Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

#INSERT COMMAND TO MAXIMIZE WINDOW HERE

End Sub
```

So, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This could be done like this as well.

```
ie.FullScreen = True
```

or

```
ie.TheaterMode = True
```

Then you don't to declare a function.

Comment: This is by far better! I think I was here in the past and didn't get past reading the above function and decided it wasn't worth the effort. No to mention the comments Re: `x32/x64` MSOffice issues which this shouldn't have. I like my macro's to be 100% portable.

Comment: Note: I used `SENDKEYS` to interact w/ IE via VBA. Upon testing `FullScreen` acted differently w/ my existing VBA Code, but `TheaterMode` worked as expected. They both look the same. Now that I know this, I would always use `TheaterMode`, but I could have of course adapted to `FullScreen`

Comment: More Notes: After using this macro, when I opened IE for other reasons manually, it was still using `TheaterMode` so I added `TheaterMode = False` to the end before I unloaded IE.

Answer (score 8):

For Internet Control, there's no inherent `Window` property. You need to use WinAPI.

This code will work :

```
'/ Win API declaration
Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" _
         (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdSHow As Long) As Long
        Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3

Sub wpieautologin()

Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Dim NOME_EMPRESA, CNPJ, CPF, COD_ACESSO As String
Dim Lookup_Range As Range

Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = False

ie.Navigate "http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/simplesnacional/controleacesso/autentica.aspx?id=6"



'// rest of your code....


'/ Win API to maximize it.
'/ Visible prop not required anymore
ShowWindow ie.hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED
End Sub
```

Check other window state at : http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-plus-of-my-favorite-windows-api-functions-to-use-in-office-applications/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When I use your code, first it says that this code must be updated to a 64bit version... So, instead of `Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" _` I must use `Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" _`... Ok, first error fixed!
So after fixing the error stated above, I get the following error: `Incompatible types` and then the debugger marks the following statement: `ShowWindow ie.hwnd` Do you know why?

Comment: dont have 64bit excel at my end, but try this link : http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp.

Comment: @rfw - Change `ByVal hwnd as Long` to `ByVal hwnd as LongPtr`.

Comment: Using the code posted by `cyboashu` and the tweak provided by `Comintern` my code worked perfectly!! Thanks for your time and effort, guys.

Comment: or You could just change `ShowWindow Clng(ie.hwnd)`